# Changing content and view for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

so I am trying to code an unsubscribe page at work with my very limited skills.

The one obstacle I have run into is trying to get the text centered on desktop without using "margin: 50%" because that will make it look really weird on mobile. Margin: auto and all other versions of that didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Also, is there a way to code different text for desktop and mobile? For example, I would like to shorten the text I have for the desktop unsubscribe version for the mobile unsubscribe version so it is a bit more compact and less text to read on mobile. 
Is that possible?

HUGE THANK YOU <3

Here's my code so far: 
     `

```
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700' type='font- family'>


    <style> 
        body        {background-color: white;}
        h4          {color: black; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans- serif; text-align: center; font-size: 20px;}
        h3          {color: black; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans- serif; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; margin-bottom:                                10px;}
        p               {color: black; font-family: 'Open Sans',  sans-serif; text-align: center; font-size: 12px;}
  label     {color: black; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  text-align: center; font-size: 12px;}
  img           {margin: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%;}
  button    {padding: 10px; width: 200px; display: block;  margin:auto;}
  .apt2b    {
        border: 1px;
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        max-width: 100%;
  }

   * Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 320px) 
 and (max-device-width : 480px) {
 /* Styles */
 }

 /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-width : 321px) {
 /* Styles */
 }

 /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (max-width : 320px) {
 /* Styles */
 }

 /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 768px) 
 and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
 /* Styles */
 }

 /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 768px) 
 and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
 and (orientation : landscape) {
 /* Styles */
 }

 /* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 768px) 
 and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
 and (orientation : portrait) {
 /* Styles */
 }

 /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-width : 1224px) {
 /* Styles */
 }

 /* Large screens ----------- */
 @media only screen 
 and (min-width : 1824px) {
 /* Styles */
 }

 /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
 @media
 only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
 only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
 /* Styles */
 }
    </style>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<meta content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-  scale=1.0" name="viewport" />

</head>


<body width = "device-width">
<div>   
<div>
   <img src="http://restorationmodern.com/Melanie/unsubscribe_banner_2.png">
</div>
 <div  class="apt2b">
   <h4>Don’t move out. We’ll even let you hold the remote to the TV.     </h4>
        <p>
    See how empty that sofa up there looks without you? We have   chips, we have soda, we have Netflix. We even have a pup. Don't leave! 
  </p>
  <h3>Just decide how cozy we should get:</h3>
<div>
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="$fields" value="EmailFrequency" />

<input id="regular" name="EmailFrequency" type="radio" value="All" />
   <label for="regular"><span></span><b>Send me all your emails.</b>         Let’s move in together. Adopt a puppy. Drink out of the same milk carton.       </label><br />

       <input checked="checked" id="email_frequency_weekly"    name="EmailFrequency" type="radio" value="weekly"/>
  <label for="email_frequency_weekly"><span></span><b>Send me a   monthly roundup of all the great stuff going on.</b> I like you, APT2B.   But not that much, so let's be neighbors. </label><br />
   <br>

   <h3>Or are you a topics connoisseur?</h3>

    <input id="regular" name="EmailFrequency" type="checkbox"  value=“newarrivals” />
   <label for="regular"><span></span> <b>Send me your new arrivals emails.</b> I need to stay on top of trends. Not subscribing to these is so 2016 after all.</label><br />

  <input id="regular" name="EmailFrequency" type="checkbox" value=“sales” />
  <label for="regular"><span></span><b>Send me all your sales emails.   </b> Nothing feels as relaxing as putting your feet up on a half-priced ottoman. </label><br />

 <input id="regular" name="EmailFrequency" type="checkbox"  value=“ideasandinspiration” />
  <label for="regular"><span></span> <b>Send me your ideas and inspirations emails.</b> Be the Thurman to my Tarantino. Let's not make three, two hour movies though.</label><br />

 <input id="regular" name="EmailFrequency" type="checkbox" value=“contestsandgiveaways” />
  <label for="regular"><span></span><b>Send me your contest and giveaway emails.</b> Win something without leaving my sofa? Uhm, yes please!</label><br />
  <br>

       <h3>Moved to another planet and don't need furniture anymore? </h3>

   <input id="email_frequency_unsubscribe" name="EmailFrequency"  type="radio" value="$unsubscribe" /> 
   <label for="email_frequency_unsubscribe"><span></span><b>  Unsubscribe me from all emails.</b> I’m done! I’m moving back to Kansas  to live with my parents.</label><br/>

   <script>
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
 if($('input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0)
    $('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
 });

$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0)
    $('input[type=radio]').removeAttr('checked');
});
</script>

<br>
  <br>
   <button type="submit">Update Preferences</button>
 </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>`
```

Comment: It's unclear what you need help with exactly. Like, center what text without "margin 50%"? Here's a helpful article on centering things. https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html And to show different content on desktop/mobile, you can just use media queries and hide/show different elements based on the viewport width.

Comment: You have to start the page with <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Enter your code here and fix the errors. https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses. Basically, I want the text centered in the middle but still aligned to the left. When I achieve this by using margin=50% it looks great on desktop, but is kind of squashed on mobile. How exactly can I change text with media queries? I never knew that was possible. Pretty cool! I'll google it. Thank you all again for your help :)